# Rewrite "x > a" in Iverson brackets as Heaviside function

Tags: logic, relations

Let's say I have a Heaviside function defined like this:

$$
H(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, \text{ if } x < 0\\
1, \text{ if } x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Then I have a so called Iverson brackets:

$$
[condition] =
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ if the condition is TRUE} \\
0, \text{ if the condition is FALSE}
\end{cases}
$$

I know I can rewrite some cases of Iverson bracket to Heaviside like this:

\begin{align}
[x \geq a]&= [x-a \geq 0] = H(x-a) \\
[x < a] &= [\neg(x \geq a)] = [\neg(x-a \geq 0)] = 1-[x - a \geq 0] = 1-H(x-a)
\end{align}

But, the question is - how can I rewrite to Heaviside the other two cases $x -a > 0$ and $x-a \leq 0$? They doesn't correspond to Heaviside func. definition and I can't use the simple negation to change them to $x -a \geq 0$ form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$[x\le a]=[x-a\le0]=H(a-x)$$$$[x\gt a]=[x-a\gt0]=1-H(a-x)$$

Comment: Oh, man... How is it possible, that I didn't think about multiplication with -1? :D ... Nevermind, thank you very much.